# Zimbra Default Admin Console

Tags: administrator, administration, zimbra

What is the default address to get to a Zimbra Admin Console? Any default ports too?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my question, it looks to be like the following:

```
https://mailserveraddress:7071/zimbraAdmin/
```